# Video codec that can be read on clean installs of either Windows, OS X and Ubuntu

Tags: video, codec

I have to make a video that will need to be watched on different operating systems. Is there a "universal" video codec that can be played on Windows, OS X and Linux without requiring additional plugins or player other than those that comes on a default clean install of each of those systems? Compression is not an issue, I'm merely looking for compatibility (e.g. for audio, I would use WAV as a universal codec).

Note : I must assume that the video will be distributed in countries where software patents are enforced, and therefore can't rely on the user to install non-free codecs on Linux.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the mjpeg family of codecs.  They're fairly simple, and it worked when I had to share movies between all three OS'es a few months back.

mencoder in linux supports this, and it did play out of the box on the few Mac and Windows systems I tested in.

Comment: I forgot to add, but I think most point-and-shoot digital cameras shoot video in this format as well.

Comment: you can edit your post to add missing information.  use the gray "edit" link between the post and these comments.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. But you can distribute Theora installers for [OS X](http://www.xiph.org/quicktime/) and [Windows](http://www.xiph.org/dshow/) for it to work with their default media player.

Answer (score 1):

MPEG2 coded videos should work on any system that can play movie-DVDs.

edit: list of codecs that come bundled with windows ->
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899113/en-us